# Installation failed. Nearby Better Together needs administrator privileges to install

Tags: failed-installation, administrative

I can't install near by share.
I pc is windows 10 ,64 bit

I selected run as administrator but not working.
I also use cmd and I on the active status but not working.
I also searched about in various types of source but i can't found solution.